# Text replacement in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

In random positions of a code with thousands of lines, I would like to pass by a string of the following type:

```
<h3><a href="/question/index?qid=20210417025215AA5DJNX" class="QuestionCard__title___1DKC-">
```

where the part `20210417025215AA5DJNX` changes from time to time, to a string of this other type:

```
17/04/2021; 02:52:15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<h3><a href="/question/index\?qid=(\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d).+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<h3><a href="/question/index\?qid=      # literally
(\d{4})         # group 1, 4 digits, year
(\d\d)          # group 2, 2 digits, month
(\d\d)          # group 3, 2 digits, day
(\d\d)          # group 4, 2 digits, hour
(\d\d)          # group 5, 2 digits, minute
(\d\d)          # group 6, 2 digits, second
.+              # 1 or more any character but newline
```

**Replacement:**

```
$3/$2/$1; $4:$5:$6
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it's perfect! A curiosity: where could I study in order to learn how to write these formulas by myself? Thanks again!

Comment: @Rolex: You're welcome, glad it helps. You'll find good tuto [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: Perfect, page already added to my favorites, have a nice day!